# Nesting Included Collections Using Custom Expressions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to keep collection properties in my model from being exposed, in accordance with this article, [Exposing Private Collection Properties to Entity Framework](http://ardalis.com/exposing-private-collection-properties-to-entity-framework). The technique demonstrated there works fine for a single level include, but I'm not able to get it to work for multiple levels.

In my example model, I have Trainers. Trainers have TrainingCourses. TrainingCourses have TrainingClasses.  I have the following defined within Trainer:

```
    public class ORMappings
    {
        public const string TrainingCoursesCollectionName = nameof(Trainer._trainingCourses);

        public static Expression<Func<Trainer, ICollection<TrainingCourse>>> TrainingCourses
        {
            get { return t => t._trainingCourses; }
        }

    }
```

This works fine (for including one collection deep), and I can refer to it like so:

```
return _dbContext.Set<Trainer>()
    .Include(Trainer.ORMappings.TrainingCoursesCollectionName);
```

or

```
// using System.Data.Entity extension
return _dbContext.Set<Trainer>()
    .Include(Trainer.ORMappings.TrainingCourses);
```

I'm referring to [the documentation on how to include nested collection properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#remarks). It suggests that the following should work:

> To include a collection and then a collection one level down:
>   query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 =>
>   l1.Level2Collection)).

However, I can't seem to find a way to use .Select() to include the TrainingClasses referenced by each TrainingCourse using the strongly typed expressions shown above (TrainingCourse has a similar ORMappings class for its list of TrainingClasses). It doesn't matter whether I try to do so outside of the ORMappings class (e.g. in a repository or similar), or within where I have direct access to my private _trainingCourses List. I would be fine to have a separate ORMappings expression that included TrainingClasses in addition to TrainingCourses, if I could get that to work. My goal is to be able to specify how deep within the collection tree the objects should be populated, so that I only load data as necessary for a given operation.

For additional reference, here is how Trainer defines its relationship with TrainingCourse:

```
private List<TrainingCourse> _trainingCourses { get; } = new List<TrainingCourse>();

public IEnumerable<TrainingCourse> TrainingCourses
{
    get
    {
        return _trainingCourses
            .Where(tc => tc.IsActive)
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMHO I think you are trying to do something really strange. If you want to "protect" the source code, you should try to explore the encapsulation keywords, like `internal` and `protected`. If you want to separate the domain classes from the infrastructure, you should create different projects. If you want to separate the domain in several parts, search for BoundedContext strategies using EntityFramework.

Backing to your question, in your current situation, I think the easiest way to solve this, is creating a new property:

```
public static Expression<Func<Trainer, IEnumerable<ICollection<TrainingClass>>>> TrainingCoursesWithClasses
{
    get { return t => t._trainingCourses.Select(i => i.TrainingClasses); }
}
```

Untested code, but if your current code works, this should work too.

In addition, be careful with this:

```
public IEnumerable<TrainingCourse> TrainingCourses
{
    get
    {
        return _trainingCourses
            .Where(tc => tc.IsActive)
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

This can possibly generate multiple enumeration of IEnumerable. If you want to get only the "IsActive == true" every time you get the property, you should create an `DbCommandTreeInterceptor`.

Furthermore, there is no reason to make the collection "private" and create a public expression that returns the collection; no reason at all. The collection could be easily accessed using:

```
var traininCoursesLambda = Trainer.TrainingCourses;
var trainingCourses = traininCoursesLambda.Compile().Invoke(trainer);
```

Hope it helps!